# Pulling elements from 2D array based on index array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array as:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
```

I also have an index array as:

```
ind = np.asarray([1,2,0,2,2])
```

The elements of ind represent the row number of A for each column of A.

i.e

I want to pull `ind[0] = 1` element from column 0 of A
I want to pull `ind[4] = 2` element from column 4 of A

Desired output is:

```
5, 11, 2, 13, 14
```

Comment: `a = [A[ind[x],x] for  x in range(5)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Numpy's `fancy-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) -

```
A[ind,np.arange(ind.size)]
```